# PyDev not seeing self-written Python 3 package

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

Right this is starting to get frustrating.  I've read [the manual on imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) and googled around and I'm obviously missing something.

I have:

```
mypkg/

mypkg/__init__.py
from .primitives import circle

mypkg/primitives/__init__.py
from .circle import vecCircle

mypkg/primitives/circle.py
```

In Project>Properties>PyDev>PYTHONPATH I have added /path/to/mypkg
In my .bash_profile I appended /path/to/mypkg to PYTHONPATH and exported.
I know I don't need both, but removing one or the other has no effect on the below.

In PyDev, I then want to do a

```
import mypkg
c = vecCircle(args)
```

but at the moment vecCircle is underlined red (`undefined variable`)

I try

```
import mypkg.primitives
c = vecCircle(args)
```

or

```
import mypkg.primitives
c = circle.vecCircle(args)
```

or

```
 import mypkg.primitives.circle
 c = circle.vecCircle(args)
```

and the only thing that changes is circle of circle.vecCircle underlines in red with the same error.  How can I get what I want?

I'm getting

```
Unused import: mypkg
Unresolved import: 
 mypkg
 Found at: mypkg.__init__
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing a module doesn't put all of its contents into your namespace (unless you use `from module import *`). Your code is just importing the module. I think the imports in the `__init__.py` files may have confused you. They import names from deeper in the package into their own namespaces, but have no effect on any namespace that imports them.

You can fix this in two ways.

The simplest approach is probably to use attribute syntax to get to the `vecCircle` value you're trying to access:

```
import mypkg

mypkg.circle.vecCircle(args)
```

If you really want to be able to access `vecCircle` directly in your own namespace, you can change the import around using `from module import name` syntax:

```
from mypkg.circle import vecCircle

vecCircle(args)
```

For both of those solutions, I've been using the shorter name `mypkg.circle.vecCircle` for the object that was originally created as `mypkg.primitives.circle.vecCircle`. The import you're doing in `mypkg/__init__.py` enables this. You could instead use `mypkg.primitives.vecCircle` if you prefer that (using a different short name, enabled by the import in `mypkg/primitives/__init__.py`).

Comment: this does sort my problem, but I never would have guessed I can omit the primitives reference due to the contents of the __init__.py.  I would rather clarify my script so it was perhaps forced to have mypkg.primitives.circle.vecCircle explicitly referenced.  I presume I can thus remove the contents of the primitive/__init__.py.

Comment: Yeah, you can remove some or all of the `__init__.py` imports if you don't want there to be shortcuts. They do load the modules for you though, so if you get rid of all of them, you'll need to do `import mypkg.primitives.circle` in your top-level code (rather than just `import mypkg`).

Answer (score 0):

Python searches directories in `PYTHONPATH` for a subdirectory with the name of the module to import.

So you need to add the parent directory of `/path/to/mypkg` to your PYTHONPATH, not `/path/to/mypkg` itself.

Comment: Cheers, but /${PROJECT_DIR_NAME} is already in the Source Folders tab in the PyDev - PYTHONPATH settings in Eclipse.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think about that after reading your tries to modify PYTHONPATH. At least my answer explains why they didn't change anything. Blckknght's answer should fix your problem.